# What does INS stand for in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

What does term INS stands for in bottom right of Visual Studio?

[image: INS]

As suggested in answer and commments, now I know that it's for INS (**Insert**) and OVR (**Overtype**) modes. [Insert Key wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key)

It's not that I didn't know about ***insert*** key usage, but I didn't know that VS shows this information.

### # Why this question is downvoted and not deleted by author

Now, to people who immediately downvoted and voted for close - I am happy that you're experts in field and helping people (without any expectation). However, before posting this question I was kind of aware this gonna happen and I did try following:

- Quick google for "INS in visual studio", "INS bottom right VS" etc returns no clue about this. .
- "INS" search returns "United States Immigration and Naturalization Service (INS)"
- "INS stands for" search
- "INS (acronym) text editor" search
- Also mentioned in comments to lemme know if this doesn't add any value to this community.

Generally I delete a question if it is downvoted (and yes I think twice before posting new question), but I don't think this was something bad or wrong to ask.

Comment: Please let me know if you think this question does not belong here.

Comment: Try hitting the INSert key on your keyboard :)

Comment: Interesting to note, while @Rohit is correct in stating that google was nigh useless in answering this before, this question is now result #4 for me. +1

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Insert</kbd>

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key)

> The Insert key (often abbreviated INS) is a key commonly found on computer keyboards.
>
> It is primarily used to switch between the two text-entering modes on a personal computer (PC) or word processor.